# Proceed if current time is within the 15 minute period after a specific time

Tags: php, time

If I have a specified time (23:55 for example), and I want to proceed if the current time is between 23:55 and 00:10, how do I do this? the specified time does not have a date attached to it.

```
$specifiedTime = '23:55';
$currentTime = '00:05';

$timeDifference = strtotime($currentTime) - strtotime($specifiedTime);

if ($timeDifference < 900) {
// proceed if less than 15 minutes has elapsed since specifiedTime
}
```

timeDifference is returned as 86700. I want it to return 600 as that is the number of seconds between the two times.

<del>UPDATE: Thanks to all. Here is the working code - big thanks to the user who removed their code which this is based on:</del>

```
$currentTime    = time();
$fromTime       = strtotime('23:55');
$toTime         = strtotime('+15 minute', $fromTime);

if ($fromTime <= $currentTime && $currentTime <= $toTime) {
    echo '<br>Current time is within 15 minutes after from time';
} else {
    echo '<br>Current time is not within 15 minutes after from time';
}
```

**UPDATE 2**: As Galvic pointed out this won't work between certain times, so i've selected Sumurai8's solution.

Comment: Can you show us your code? Doesn't php date have date part?

Comment: Questions asking for code should show a **minimum** understanding of the problem, which means you should include previous attempts, why they didn't work and expected results.

Comment: `timeDifference` is returning correct negative number, because time `00:05` is not larger than `23:55` (for same date). `strtotime` appends current date to your time, so `strtotime($currentTime)` is equal to `strtotime('2013-09-28 00:05')`; same goes for $specifiedTime.

Comment: Your UPDATE code will not work if your current time `$currentTime` is between `00:00` and `00:10`...

Comment: Thanks for that, i've edited my question and selected Sumurai8's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you made a typo, because your code suggests this would return -85800. You most likely want to use the modulo operator, which will give the remainder of a division. See [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php). The `+ 86400` (24*60*60) is to ensure the result is always positive. `% 86400` will divide the answer by 86400 and return whatever remains. `600 % 86400 = 600`, while `86800 % 86400 = 400`.

```
$specifiedTime = '23:55';
$currentTime = '00:05';

$timeDifference = (strtotime($currentTime) - strtotime($specifiedTime) + 86400) % 86400;

if ($timeDifference < 900) {
// proceed if less than 15 minutes has elapsed since specifiedTime
}
```

Comment: Cheers for the solution, i've selected this is the answer.